# Make elements fill rows but overflow to new rows after three columns, filling width / spaced evenly

Tags: css

I'm trying to make elements fill a container row-by-row (not masonry), expanding to completely fill the row and spaced evenly, with up to three elements per row. *(I think this **must** be covered by previous questions, but I haven't been able to find what I'm looking for.)*

This snippet shows the result I'm looking for with one element, two elements, three, etc. (using grid in this case, but I'm not bothered whether it's grid, flex, or whatever), but it's seriously ugly and requires I have CSS classes for each variant (`columns-1`, `columns-2`, etc.) and that I specify the right class for its contents on the container:

```css
/* Basic Styles */
html,
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
    padding: 8px;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 0.5rem;
    font-size: inherit;
}

/* The container for items */
.container {
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 8px;

    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 4px;
    grid-column-gap: 4px;
    justify-items: stretch;
}

/* An item in the container */
.container > span {
    background-color: #8ab1de;
    color: #1a2550;
    font-weight: 600;
    min-width: fit-content;
    padding: 4px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    flex-basis: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Additional styles for container for ONE item */
.container.columns-1 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}
/* Additional styles for container for TWO items */
.container.columns-2 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}
/* Additional styles for container for THREE items */
.container.columns-3 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}
/* Additional styles for container for FOUR items */
.container.columns-4 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}
/* Additional styles for container for FIVE items */
.container.columns-5 {
    grid-template-areas:
        "a a b b c c"
        "d d d e e e";
}
.container.columns-5 :nth-child(1) {
    grid-area: a;
}
.container.columns-5 :nth-child(2) {
    grid-area: b;
}
.container.columns-5 :nth-child(3) {
    grid-area: c;
}
.container.columns-5 :nth-child(4) {
    grid-area: d;
}
.container.columns-5 :nth-child(5) {
    grid-area: e;
}

/* Additional styles for container for SIX items */
.container.columns-6 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}

/* Seven or more would be unhandled */
```

```html
<h2>One item:</h2>
<div class="container columns-1">
    <span>Some Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Two:</h2>
<div class="container columns-2">
    <span>Some Item</span>
    <span>Some Other Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Three:</h2>
<div class="container columns-3">
    <span>Some Item</span>
    <span>Some Other Item</span>
    <span>Another Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Four:</h2>
<div class="container columns-4">
    <span>Some Item</span>
    <span>Some Other Item</span>
    <span>Another Item</span>
    <span>A Fourth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Five:</h2>
<div class="container columns-5">
    <span>Some Item</span>
    <span>Some Other Item</span>
    <span>Another Item</span>
    <span>A Fourth Item</span>
    <span>A Fifth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Six:</h2>
<div class="container columns-6">
    <span>Some Item</span>
    <span>Some Other Item</span>
    <span>Another Item</span>
    <span>A Fourth Item</span>
    <span>A Fifth Item</span>
    <span>A Sixth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>And so on...</h2>
```

So:

- For one, two, or three elements, put them in a single row filling the available space fairly evenly
- For four elements, put two on each row, with four elements of equal size
- For five elements, put three spaced evenly in the first row and two in the second
- For six elements, three per row of equal size

Ideally, with unvarying markup other than the actual items, so for one element:

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Some Item</span>
</div>
```

for three:

```html
<div class="container">
    <span>Some Item</span>
    <span>Some Other Item</span>
    <span>Another Item</span>
</div>
```

and so on.

In an ideal world, the number of elements per row would be dynamically determined from their content (akin to `fit-content`) rather than being the arbitrary number I've given (3), but with the specific use case I have, if I have to pick an arbitrary number, I can.

I'm trying to solve this with CSS, rather than JavaScript. If it's not possible, then I'll write the JavaScript to do it, but I'm hoping my struggle here is my CSS ignorance.

Comment: no more than 6 element in total?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - That would do for now and presumably I could extend any solution that does that to nine if I needed to. That said, it would be great if it were flexible enough not to really care how many elements there were... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an idea using flexbox where you adjust the flex-basis based on the number of elements using nth-child

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.container>span {
  background-color: #8ab1de;
  color: #1a2550;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 4px; /* only column */
}

.container>* {
  flex: 1; /* same width at each row */
}

/* when 4 elements */
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ * {
  flex-basis: 40%; /* bigger than 33% and smaller than 50% */
}
/* when 5 elements and more */
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(n + 5),
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(n + 5) ~ * {
  flex-basis: 30%; /* bigger than 25% and smaller than 33% */
}
```

```html
<h2>One item:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Two:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Three:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Four:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Five:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Six:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
  <span>A Sixth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>And so on...</h2>
```

Going to 9 elements:

```css
h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 0.5rem;
  font-size: inherit;
}

.container>span {
  background-color: #8ab1de;
  color: #1a2550;
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 4px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 4px; /* only column */
}

.container>* {
  flex: 1; /* same width at each row */
}

/* when 4 elements */
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(4),
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ *{
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
/* when 5 elements and more */
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(n + 5),
.container > :first-child:nth-last-child(n + 5) ~ * {
  flex-basis: 30%;
}
/* when 7 elements */
.container > :nth-child(4):nth-last-child(4),
.container > :nth-child(4):nth-last-child(4) ~ *{
  flex-basis: 40%;
}
```

```html
<h2>One item:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Two:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Three:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Four:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Five:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Six:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
  <span>A Sixth Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Seven:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
  <span>A Sixth Item</span>
  <span>A 7 Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Eight:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
  <span>A Sixth Item</span>
  <span>A 7 Item</span>
  <span>A 8 Item</span>
</div>

<h2>Nine:</h2>
<div class="container">
  <span>Some Item</span>
  <span>Some Other Item</span>
  <span>Another Item</span>
  <span>A Fourth Item</span>
  <span>A Fifth Item</span>
  <span>A Sixth Item</span>
  <span>A 7 Item</span>
  <span>A 8 Item</span>
  <span>A 9 Item</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm really surprised it's so hacky to do this in modern CSS, it seems like a fairly normal use case. I'm not thrilled at all the CSS needed, but at least I don't have to output classes on the container to say how many children it has! :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder even with modern CSS the browser cannot switch between different layouts alone. Between 3 and 4 then 4 and 5 there is a *big* change. BTW, I can find less verbose solutions later. This one is what comes to my mind at first. I think I can get rid of the pseudo element (will make an update when I get time)

Comment: I appreciate your time, thanks!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder updated the code, it was easier than what I expected. flex-basis alone was already enough

Comment: Oh, wow, that's much cleaner! I did try `flex-basis` but not...adequately. ;-D Thanks, I'll study it!